# Swift Error: Cannot find an initializer for type 'Double' that accepts an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am trying to grab data from a text field labeled 'temperatureTextField' and assigning it to 't' which is a Double. Ideally the user is meant to add a number value to the temperatureTextField.

Here is my method:

```
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func convert(sender: AnyObject) {
    let t = Double(temperatureTextField.text!)
    let tempM = TemperatureModel(temp: t!)
    temperatureTextField.text = String(tempM.toCelsius())
}
```

The red exclamation is coming from the line "let t = Double(temperatureTex...)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using Xcode 6, so Swift 1.2, but the String initializer for Double is only available in Swift 2 (Xcode 7).

You can always use NSString's doubleValue property:

```
let t = (temperatureTextField.text! as NSString).doubleValue
```

but I'd recommend using Xcode 7 and Swift 2 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

As Eric suggested, I ran into this issue because I was running an outdated version of xcode.
Here is what my code looked liked after, in case anyone runs into trouble and is unable to update:

```
let t = (inputText.text! as NSString).doubleValue
let tempModel = TemperatureModel(temp: t)
inputText.text = "\(tempModel.toCelsius())"
```